# How can BlueCove be used in Android?

Tags: android, bluecove

I'm trying to implement BlueCove in Android; i've read here: http://code.google.com/p/bluecove/source/browse/trunk/bluecove-android2/src/site/apt/index.apt?r=3062  "usage: include bluecove.jar and bluecove-android2.jar in classpath of the android application and call JSR-82 APIs normally" .

The problem is that if i include bluecove.jar and bluecove-android2.jar i get a "The library 'bluecove-2.1.0.jar' contains native libraries that will not run on the device." error about  libbluecove.jnilib.

How can i solve it?

Comment: tried this? http://groups.google.com/group/bluecove-developers/msg/847f714034b34126

Answer (score 0):

BlueCove uses native calls through JNI, you will need implement those calls with android equivalents.

This might help: http://groups.google.com/group/bluecove-developers/browse_thread/thread/6e32131d7c5b672